# xcode 8.3.3 Playground does not show the error next to line number

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

For some reason my xcode 8.3.3 `does not show the errors next to line numbers`. **Errors are showing up at the top bar** and **also in the issue navigator if opened**. Is there something I am missing. Sometimes the playground execution is slow as well.

Opening the error in `issue navigator` does not populate the auto fix options when clicked on the suggested fix by XCode.

[image: error indicator missing in the line number bar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this menu(although it's already shown):

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. it worked. never thought of it being that sample. What was i using then ? how does that impact ? if you don't mind elaborating ?

Comment: The Version Editor will hide the red error on line number. Maybe the Xcode thought it's in Version Editor mode.

Comment: Playground still sometimes don't show the error message if run `alone` i.e XCode > New Playground. if playground file is created from a project i.e. File > New > Playground, Everything works perfect.

Comment: @rulebreaker4, nice find!